# Avoid postLoad call on not instanced class using doctrine.event_listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a Symphony 3.4 project with has more than 150 classes, which almost all have declared the postLoad method of doctrine.event_listener.

Thus I have more than 150 calls on a postLoad and only execute the method in very few for each request, since I have the if in PostLoad checking that the class instantiated is the one each method uses.

```
public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $article = $args->getEntity();
    if ($article instanceof Article) {
```

If I'm loading another entity the code is not executed but the postLoad is fired anyway.

Is there a way to avoid this call (postLoad) when the class is not even instantiated ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/650

using the tag doctrine.orm.entity_listener for the listener.